# ModX: Changed to Friendly Alias URLS but now Wayfinder isnt working

Tags: url, modx, modx-revolution

I've used Wayfinder in my template, eg:

```
[[Wayfinder? &startId=`8` ]]
```

and it was working fine until I turned on friendly urls (by going: System>>System Settings>>User Friendly URLS)

Now none of my links work. On top of this if I click the 'View' button from a resource page or enter the full url into a browser I get a 404 error.

Am I missing something in this process?

(ps Im using Revo 2.1.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you configured your .htaccess file? It's required for friendly urls. When you install MODX it's named `ht.access`, so you'll need to rename it to `.htaccess`.

If you've installed MODX in a subfolder you'll also need to set it here:

```
RewriteBase /folder-name
```

As Sean suggested, you'll also need to clear your cache to have your Wayfinder menu rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

it's probably your cache - just clear it and you should be fine.